# Apache Beam Pipeline - Exception Error Handling

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline that reads from a reference table in Datastore and performs certain processing tasks on data streaming in from Google Pubsub. However, I'm facing some issues as below:

```
Entity referenceEntity = getDataStoreEntity(projectId, kind, key);

if (referenceEntity != null) {
    Integer prop1 = (int) referenceEntity.getLong("prop1");
    Double prop2 = referenceEntity.getDouble("prop2");
    String prop3 = referenceEntity.getString("prop3");
}
```

(1) Somehow if there is no property defined in the referenceEntity in datastore, the pipeline will throw a NullPointerException. I thought data classes like Integer, Double and String are able to hold null values? How can I make the pipeline handle this error that will execute functions only if the values are available? e.g. if(prop1 != null) {...}

(2) Sometimes when there is no referenceEntity in datastore, there are also errors thrown. I might be wrong, but does getDataStoreEntity throw an exception error, or will it just emit a null value if the entity is not found?

By the way the function getDataStoreEntity is written based on package: com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore using the .get method.

```
public static Entity getDataStoreEntity(String projectId, String kind, String key) {
    final Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.newBuilder()
                                                .setProjectId(projectId)
                                                .build().getService();

    // The Cloud Data store key for the new entity
    final Key referenceKey = datastore.newKeyFactory()
                                      .setKind(kind)
                                      .newKey(key);

    return datastore.get(referenceKey);

}
```

Comment: Your program contains a cast from Integer to int: (int). In Java, Integer can hold a null value, but int can not - hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: But the issue is that when you try to reference that particular property, it's already throwing a Null Exception Error before it's being cast. Many of the error messages i encountered reference any one of those lines.

Comment: Could you include the full error stack trace?

Comment: com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: No such property vref
at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException.throwInvalidRequest (DatastoreException.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.BaseEntity.getValue (BaseEntity.java:523)
at com.google.cloud.datastore.BaseEntity.getDouble (BaseEntity.java:568)
at com.project.transform.convertFn.process (convertFn.java:59)

Comment: How about checking referenceEntity.contains() before accessing the property?

Comment: Ahh.. that sounds like a good approach. Thanks @jkff! I didn't know there's a contains method, will definitely try it out!